# Rails 3, comments in a nested form, wrong routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, nested, has-one

I have a **Posts** model, which has many posts in many **languages**. It's a bit non-standard, but to illustrate:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :eng_post, :dependent => :destroy         # <-- HAS_ONE!
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :eng_post, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

I.e. a Post has one EngPost. Whereas EngPost is defined in the model as:

```
class EngPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :eng_comments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :eng_comments, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :eng_comments_attributes
end
```

And finally, the eng_comments model is:

```
class EngComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eng_post, :foreign_key => "eng_post_id"
end
```

The routes.rb defines:

```
resources :posts do
  resource :eng_posts
end

resource :eng_post do
  resources :eng_comments
end

resources :eng_comments
```

The problem - can't render the Post **with** the eng_comments, I tried:

```
<% form_for ([@post, @post.eng_post, @post.eng_post.eng_comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

and tried:

```
<% form_for @comment do |f| %>
```

This results in error

```
undefined method `post_eng_post_eng_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000067de2a8>:0x000000067c4498>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eng_comments also need to be nested:

```
resources :posts do
   resource :eng_post do #no 's'
       resources :eng_comments
   end
end

resources :eng_posts do
     resources :eng_comments
end

resources :eng_comments
```

If you were using
`<% form_for ([@post.eng_post, @post.eng_post.eng_comments.build]) do |f| %>`
then your current routes would work.

---

ps:
you might want to prepare all the variables in the controller (especially the eng_comment):

```
def new
    @post = Post.find...
    @eng_comment = @post.eng_post.eng_comments.build
end
```

So that you can do:

```
<% form_for ([@post, @post.eng_post, @eng_comment]) do |f| %>
```

The advantage is that you'll be able to use the exact same form to edit the comment (even if  the comments can't be edited in your app, I think it's a good practice).

Comment: Robin, thanks for your answer. But the only way it would render is with <% form_for ([@post, @post.eng_post, @post.eng_post.eng_comments.build]) do |f| %> . Still the comments form isn't rendered, and debug's output is --- !ruby/object:EngComment
attributes:
  id: !!null 
  eng_post_id: 97
  full_name: !!null 
  website: !!null 
  email: !!null 
  comment: !!null 
  created_at: !!null 
  updated_at: !!null

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion works, after adding 
resources :eng_posts do
     resources :eng_comments
end

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to nest the resources like this in your `routes.rb`

```
resources :posts do
  resource :eng_posts do 
    resource :eng_comments
  end
end
```

This should give you paths like this: `/posts/:id/eng_posts/:id/eng_comments/[:id]`

That way the `post_eng_post_eng_comments_path` should exist.. (better try it out with `rake routes`)