# Comments form can't be rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, comments, nested, rendering

Rails 3 can't render the comments form for some reason, the form is:

```
<% form_for ([@post.eng_post, @post.eng_post.eng_comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

but

```
<%= debug @post.eng_post.eng_comments.build %>
```

gives

```
--- !ruby/object:EngComment
attributes:
  id: !!null 
  eng_post_id: 97
  full_name: !!null 
  website: !!null 
  email: !!null 
  comment: !!null 
  created_at: !!null 
  updated_at: !!null
```

The models are structured as:

```
Posts (have one)-> EngPost (has many)-> EngComments
```

(More detailed models are here [Rails 3, comments in a nested form, wrong routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687990/rails-3-comments-in-a-nested-form-wrong-routes))

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `<% form_for` with `<%= form_for`

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm actually migrating from rails 2. There are so many little things like this one! :)